# Images contained in the buttons disappear after adding a new item to the WPF listview

Tags: wpf, listview, gridviewcolumn

Within a GridViewColumn in a listView I have three buttons (delete, move up and move down item) in the same column. Delete button will always be shown. However Move Up and Move down buttons are collapsed or not depending if they have sense (for example, if the listview only has 1 item, only delete button will be shown, if it has more than 1 item, first item only shows delete and move down buttons and last item, delete and move up buttons). The look of the buttons are as below (I post here only one):

```
<Image x:Key="ImgDelete" Source="pack://application:,,,/Sys;component/Resources/ImageDelete.png"

<Button Content="{StaticResource ImgDelete}"
        Margin="10 0 0 0"
        Height="24"
        Width="24"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.DeleteCommand, ElementName=myListView}"                             
        CommandParameter="{Binding (ItemsControl.AlternationIndex),
                           RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListViewItem}}"/>
```

The buttons contain a 24x24 png image as you can see above.

Also in the first row of the ListView I have an "Add" button to add items to the ListView.
Initially the ListView is empty.

I add first item to the listview and it is added correctly, the button with the image inside is shown. See below:

[image]

Then I add a second item to the listview and this is added correctly, the button with its image is shown BUT the previous item I added before to the listview (the first one), its delete and move down buttons are shown BUT with no image inside (the image has disappeared). See below:

[image]

If I add another item to the listview:

[image]

and so on....

As you see, when adding a new item to the listview, in all the previous ones the image of the buttons disappears.

Any ideas what's happening?

Comment: It is quite natural because there is only one instance of that `Image` control.

Comment: Just set `x:Shared="false"` on the Image resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An instance of `Image` is required for each instance of `Button`.

So add derived class of `BitmapSource` such as `BitmapImage` in Window.Resources and elsewhere and refer it from each `Image` instance. In addition, I would recommend to set [PresentationOptions:Freeze](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/presentationoptions-freeze-attribute) in the `BitmapImage`.

```xml
<BitmapImage x:Key="ImageDeleteKey"
             UriSource="Resources/ImageDelete.png"
             PresentationOptions:Freeze="True"/>
```

```xml
<Button>
    <Image Source="{StaticResource ImageDeleteKey}"/>
</Button>
```

**EDIT:**

The solution suggested by Clemens `x:Shared="False"` also works. In comparison with that solution, this solution will be better in memory efficiency (less memory usage) but the practical impact will depend on the size of image file.

Comment: It works but in your BitmapImage you forget to include namespaces: xmlns:PresentationOptions="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/options" and xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" and also mc:Ignorable="PresentationOptions". If you not include them then PresentationOptions:Freeze is not recognized and an error is thrown in design time. So please, correct include them in your post. Also i would like to know which is the difference between yours and mine using x:Shared="false" attribute suggested by Clemens. Which one is best?

Comment: Also what does PresentationOprtions_Freeze exactly do? I have read your provided link but I am not be able to understand it. Could you please explain what it does? What is the purpose of using it? If I not use it what would happens? refresh issues?

Comment: Added the comparion with that solution. The document I linked explains the namespaces and include the usefuil link to Freezable.